# How to transfer HTML code to another aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My requirement is below:

I am calling a function from my aspx page which returns HTML (authentication form from Google). I need to pass this HTML to another page and show this form in that page.

```
clsTest c = new clsTest("31865d34927072.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                                 "code", "offline", "http://abc.comAccount/Login.aspx",
                                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
var k = c.GetAccessDetails().ToString();
Response.Redirect("authPage.aspx?html=" + k);
```

I am using Response.redirect and passing this as a query string which is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: `redirect('newpage?html=blahblahblah')`?

Comment: You're asking for a fatal XSS vulnerability.

Comment: use session add remove it after use

Comment: Your problem is that you don't say what "not working" means.

Comment: Session is a good suggestion

Comment: That's an awful lot of junk to throw into session.  Why not call GetAccessDetails within authpage.aspx.cs::OnPreRender and just emit the HTML inline in the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give more information what is not working but to stop XSS and CSRF attack i suggest using of session would be better than query string 
you can use your session like this

```
Session ["Authenticate"] = c.GetAccessDetails().ToString();
if (Session ["Authenticate"] != null )
{
Response.Redirect("authPage.aspx");
}
```

and in your other page access the session like

```
string test = Session ["Authenticate"].Tostring();
```

this will make it harder for any one to do XSS or CSRF attack 
and you can use the session until the session exist

Answer (score 0):

Why put it in the Session object then get it when the new page loads.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["something for page xyz"] = "some stuff";
```

Then in the next page

```
String s = HttpContext.Current.Session["something for page xyz"];
```

Tip: Passing anything other than simple text on the url is not a good idea.

Comment: When you're within a page context and have the correct namespace imported, there's no need to access via `HttpContext.Current`. You can just directly use Session.